# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format' in keras resnet50

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Resnet50 model for training.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras_applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')

input_layer = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights=None, classes=2)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Why is the following error showing up?

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model.py", line 42, in <module>
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=input_layer, classes=2)
File "/home/mario/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/resnet50.py", line 209, in ResNet50
data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'
```

Comment: Update your tensorflow and Keras! It works fine.

Comment: I have the latest versions

Answer (score 5):

I hit this issue as well.

Please try this. It works very well:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Answer (score 3):

I hit a similar issue. It worked by changing `keras_applications` to `keras.applications`.

They have an issue on GitHub and still open: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/issues/54