# ResNet50v2 in Keras

Tags: keras, resnet, pre-trained-model

I want to load pre-trained ResNet50v2 model in Keras. I tried

```
keras.applications.resnet_v2.ResNet50V2()
```

This gave an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'resnet_v2'
```

On searching that error, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730330/3337089) suggested to use `keras_applications` package. So I tried

```
keras_applications.resnet_v2.ResNet50V2()
```

This gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nagabhushan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/resnet_common.py", line 495, in ResNet50V2
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/nagabhushan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/resnet_common.py", line 348, in ResNet
    data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'
```

On searching that error, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139293/3337089) suggests to use `keras.applications` package. I'm confused. How can I load ResNetv2 model?

Note: I was able to load ResNet50. Only ResNet50v2 is giving problems

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
import keras

keras.applications.resnet_v2.ResNet50V2()
```

The above code is executed in the jupyter notebook

Before installing Keras, please install one of its backend engines TensorFlow

- pip install tensorflow
- pip install keras

[image]

Comment: Worked! I was using `tensorflow-gpu` and `keras-gpu`. Tried with just `tensorflow` and `keras`. It worked.